# Using regular expression for validating a german car license

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for the perfect regular expression for validation a german car license
the number has too look like this:

> 1-3 Letters
>   a MINUS (i know the minus is now out of date, but the customer want it that way)
>   1-2 Letters
>   a SPACE
>   1-4 numbers

m a 12 --> wrong
abc a 12 --> wrong
m-a 12 --> correct
abc-abc 12 --> wrong
abc-ab-12 --> wrong
abc-ab 1234 --> correct
ab-ab 1234 --> correct
abc-ab 12345 wrong

I was using `([a-z]+)[-]?([a-z]*)\s*(\d+)` (so without counting numbers) but it was going the wrong way.

Comment: i was using `([a-z]+)[-]?([a-z]*)\s*(\d+)` (wo without counting numbers) but it was going the wrong way...

Comment: you should put that in your question and also specify the language you are using

Comment: done... but i think the language doesn't matters, or?

Comment: well it matters a lot..for example **some** `regex` implementations doesn't recognize `\d`..As the tag wiki of regex suggests,`you must include the tag for the specific language`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}-[a-zA-Z]{1,2} \d{1,4}$
```

This roughly breaks down into:

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]{1,3}` A letter between 1 and 3 times (inclusive)
- `-` A hyphen
- `[a-zA-Z]{1,2}` A letter between 1 and 2 times (inclusive)
- A space character
- `\d{1,4}` A digit (0 - 9) between 1 and 4 times (inclusive)
- `$` The end of the string

Comment: thanks for explaining this... i really hope to get more into this

Comment: @Joerg No problem - Regexes can on first glance look quite imposing, but once you get used to the parts that they're composed of they're much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}-[a-zA-Z]{1,2} \d{1,4}$
```

---

`[a-zA-Z]` matches a single character

`[a-zA-Z]{1,3}` matches 1 to 3 characters

`\d` is similar to [0-9]

`\d{1,4}` matches 1 to 4 digits